# How to get only timestamp from the below file name

Tags: bash

File Name:

rms_mm_store_sales_20230228998765.dat.gz

Output should be: 20230228998765

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Are there more variations to the file name format?

Comment: Is the format always the same or does it change (ex: length...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use sed

```
ls -1 | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'
```

`ls -1` to get one file per line

`[^0-9]*` to select all the non numerical character and replace them by nothing will also to keep only numbers

Answer (score 0):

If you use sed with numbers in filename :

```
echo "rms_mm_store_sal1es_20230228998765.dat.gz" | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'
120230228998765
```

Maybe use awk

```
echo "rms_mm_store_sal1es_20230228998765.dat.gz" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $(NF-2)}'
20230228998765
```